# Test whether two predictions are significantly different

Tags: r, prediction

I am currently stuck with a problem regarding predictions from linear regressions. I estimated a simple (multivariate) regression model y = b0 + b1 * x + b2 * X, where x is my variable of interest and X is a matrix of controls, using the `lm()` fct in R.

Now I want to predict y for two different values of x. Finally, I want to know whether those two predictions of y are statistically different from each other.

So far, I used `predict(model, se.fit = TRUE, interval = "prediction")` and got a point prediction as well as the corresponding prediction interval. Using the prediction intervals of the two points, I decided whether there are statistically different based on the overlapping of the prediction intervals.

I got almost no significant differences using this technique even when the estimated coefficients are significant. Is this the right track, or are there different techniques one can use?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please tell us what it is supposed to mean for two predictions to be "statistically different."  "Overlapping of the prediction intervals" gives us some hints, but it's not a valid approach to any kind of rigorous analysis (it's an *ad hoc* comparison unrelated to the actual purpose of a prediction interval), which leaves us uncertain about what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: First, I agree with @whuber. Second, I wonder how you could potentially decide that the two predictions are "statistically the same" if you have an estimated underlying model telling that the effect of $x$ on $y$ is linear with size $\beta_1$ (I know you have not decided that yet, but you are posing a question). So if you put $x_0$ in place of $x$ and another $x_1$ in place of $x$, and $x_0 \neq x_1$, you know you will get a different $y$: $y(x_0) \neq y(x_1)$. Unless you cannot reject a hypothesis that $\beta_1=0$, the two predictions will be different. Something is confusing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want this, or if I really understand what you want; however `predict()` will give you what I think you want. It makes the assumption that future values will have the same variance of the data used to construct your model. You can change that, but let's assume you think that is good assumption. If you change your interval to confidence, rather than prediction, you will get upper and lower bounds for for a 95% confidence interval that the true value of the mean for your observation is within the interval. Prediction interval is not what you want. Prediction intervals give you 95% confidence interval that future values will fall within that interval ([an overview](http://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1506/) of different intervals). You don't care about future values. You care about the values you are comparing.

So, comparing intervals from the following function, `predict(model, se.fit = TRUE, interval = "confidence")`, will tell you whether you have sufficient confidence that the true value of the mean of an observation is greater than the true value of the mean of another observation.

I used some stylized verbiage, because, again, I am not sure exactly what you want. If you want to know whether one value is greater than another value, then you don't need statistics. It either is or it isn't. If someone got an A on a test, and someone else got a B, you can't ask if the first person statistically got a better grade. They just plain got a better grade. If you have more data points though, you can estimate if the first person, on average, does better on tests than the second person.

I think a key distinction to make is that your model does not predict values, per se. It predict *means*. What your model gives you is an estimate of the mean for a random variable $y$ for a person with certain $x$ and $\mathbf X$ values. One way to think of it is that there could be multiple people with those same $x$ and $\mathbf X$ values, but you wouldn't necessarily get the same value (hence the error component). While this adds complexity that isn't in your model, you also could imagine measuring the same person at different intervals. Even if the $x$ and $\mathbf X$ variables didn't change, you would still imagine the measured DV value would be different. So you aren't really saying that predicted value 1 is larger than predicted value 2. You are saying something to the extent of the mean for all people with certain $x$ and $\mathbf X$ values is greater or less than the mean for all people with certain other $x$ and $\mathbf X$ values, with 95% confidence.

P.S. I say "people" because I study people. If you study plants or rocks or plots of farmland, just insert those words where I put people.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with the R portion of the question, but the general situation is this:

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the exact (unobservable) values of the two responses.

Then 
$$ y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2X + \epsilon_1,$$
$$ y_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_2 + \beta_2X + \epsilon_2.$$

You approximate $y_1-y_2$ by the estimated difference $\widehat{y_1 - y_2} = b_1(x_1-x_2)$.
Under the standard assumptions about the residuals, $\widehat{y_1 - y_2}$ has the expected value  $\beta_1(x_1-x_2)$. The error in the difference of the predictions comes from two sources: error in the estimate $b_1$, and random error $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$. You can estimate the standard deviation of the error by
$${\rm{Var}}[y_1-y_2] \approx \left({\rm{Var}}(b_1)\right)(x_1-x_2)^2+2\sigma^2.$$
You are interested in testing whether the estimated difference $\widehat{y_1 - y_2}$ is statistically significant(ly different from zero). That is a t-test; the test statistic is

$${b_1(x_1-x_2)}\over{\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2*{\rm{Var}}(b_1) + 2\sigma^2}}$$
with degrees of freedom equal to twice the degrees of freedom of the error in the regression model.

Comment: It's a good interpretation of the question. But how do you deduce that the DF should be *twice* the DF of the error?  Where does this "free" information come from?  And how, exactly, is the expression in the denominator developed?  (I believe it is missing an additive term and that the factor of "$SE(\beta_1)$", whatever it might mean (a parameter has no standard error), is incorrect.)

Comment: I corrected a couple of typos in my answer. The degrees of freedom and the standard deviation in the numerator come from standard assumptions about the residuals: The residuals $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are independent of each other, they are independent of everything else in the model, and they have the same variance $\sigma^2$. Because of independence, the degrees of freedom are additive.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. It's still hard to tell what you're doing. Are you, or are you not, (1) treating $X$ as a random variable and (2) treating the parameter $\beta_1$ as a random variable? At various times you have referred to the variances of both of these, suggesting they should be considered random. That has implications for the denominator of the t-statistic--which, btw, still has typos in it (since $SE(b_1)$ needs to be squared). You also seem to confound the "estimated difference" of the y's with their *actual* difference, for otherwise the $2\sigma^2$ term should not appear.

Comment: @whuber. Thanks. I'll get it right one of these days... The point is that predictions are subject to two errors: estimation error of the model, and random error. I chose to take the OP by his/her word ("to predict y for two different values of x" --- note the lower case, so I take the controls X as fixed). I hope my derivation is now correct.